# redirecting to aspx page from mvc controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i have a project created in asp.net and now the new pages are implemented using mvc 
so 
i want to redirect to an aspx page from mvc controller but when I do Redirect("Login.aspx") in the action method, it shows the resource could not be found.

Comment: Use `return Redirect("~/YourPage.aspx")`

Comment: it doesnt matter if your view is built using asp or razor, just follow the mvc convention that if you will call and MVC controller then it will definitely serve you the right view `automatically`. Just use the following code. `RedirectToAction("ActionName")`

Comment: I have tried Redirect("~/Login.aspx") as well

Comment: actually the asp.net code and mvc code is on different local hosts so its not able to identify the page

Answer (score 0):

You can create mvc action and call rendering of a partial view in the apropriate action's view

```
@Html.Partial("<Path to my aspx page>/Page.aspx")
```

in aspx page Inherits must be specifyed:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>
```

Comment: The partial view '~/ASPX/UserManagement.aspx' was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/ASPX/UserManagement.aspx

Comment: you need to pass path of aspx page to the `Partial` method (absolute or relative to your mvc project). In my solution I manually created `/ASPX/` folder in the mvc project to hold aspx pages. Edited my answer to specify this detail.

Comment: if you have aspx project and mvc project on separate servers, then this wouldn't work and you can only perform `return Redirect("<full_aspx_project_url>/YourPage.aspx")` in mvc action